# Extend the Existing User Model with AbstractUser method error object 'User' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to extend user but getting errors

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'bffcode.User'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    fb_userid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    objects =AbstractUser()
```

**views.py**

```
def fb_login(request):
     users = User.objects.filter(fb_userid=fb_user_id)
```

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've set the `objects` attribute of your User class to an instance of AbstractUser. It is supposed to be a Manager.

Unless you actually have a custom Manager subclass, it's best to leave this alone; you should delete that line.

Comment: I have deleted this line but still getting same error

Comment: Please edit the question to show the whole traceback.